# Anyone recognize this Syntax or Programming Language?

Tags: database

I am the local admin for an obsucure CRM-ATS prior to migrating to SFDC in 18 mos.  It has a (basically BETA) report builder that is not well documented, but, appears very powerful.  I have the capabilities to build custom expressions within the report, but, I can't figure the syntax for all the operators.

Does anyone recognize this code or operators list that might be able to point me to the proper language for syntax and creation of these individual expressions.

```
IF(GREATER_OR_EQUAL(DATE_DIFF(NOW(); JobCurrentStep.StepTime); 14); SUBSTRING("14Days+"; 1); SUBSTRING("<14 Days"; 1))

DATE_DIFF(StepsLinkedPeop.StepStartTime; StepsLinkedPeop.StepEndTime)

COUNT_DISTINCT(People.Person)

IF(LIKE(LinkedJobs.JobClientNameSBD; "MSP"); COUNT_DISTINCT(People.Person); 9)

COUNT_DISTINCT(People.Person)

IF(GREATER_OR_EQUAL(DATE_DIFF(StepChangesJour.StepStartTime; NOW()); 30); COUNT_DISTINCT(People.Person); 0

COUNT_DISTINCT(LinkedPeople.Applicant)

COUNT(LinkedPeople.Applicant)

DATE_DIFF(StepChangesJour.StepEndTime; StepChangesJour.StepStartTime)

GREATER_OR_EQUAL(DATE_DIFF(StepChangesJour.StepEndTime; StepChangesJour.StepStartTime); 7)

DATE_DIFF(NOW(); JobCurrentStep.StepTime)

IF(GREATER_OR_EQUAL(DATE_DIFF(NOW(); JobCurrentStep.StepTime); 500); SUBSTRING("Greater than 2 Weeks"; 1); SUBSTRING("Recent"; 1))
```

---

Here are the available operators:

```
AVG
CONCAT
COUNT
COUNT_DISTINCT
DATE_ADD_DAYS
DATE_ADD_SECONDS
DATE_DIFF
DATE_DIFF_IN_SECONDS
DATE_DIFF_IN_YEARS
DATE_FORMAT
DIVISION
EQUALS
GREATER
GREATER_OR_EQUAL
GROUP_CONCAT
GROUP_CONCAT_DISTINCT
GROUP_CONCAT_DISTINCT_WITH_HYPHEN
GROUP_CONCAT_DISTINCT_WITH_PIPES
HOUR_DIFF
IF
IF_NULL
IN
INET_NTOA
LIKE
LITERAL_NULL
LOCATE
LOGGED_USER_ID
LOGGED_USER_PERSON_ID
LOGGED_USER_TIMEZONE
MAX
MIN
MINUS
MULTIPLY
NOW
PCT
PLUS
REPLACE
ROUND
SUBSTRING
SUBSTRING_INDEX
SUM
SUM_DISTINCT
TO_DATETIME
TO_INT
TRIM
TRUNCATE
WORKING_DAYS
```

Comment: What kind of question is this? If you can't help your self to find which language is this then how you are expecting others to help you to find it out?

Comment: The syntax seems to be very simple: `OPERATOR(PARAM1;PARAM2;PARAMN)`. Looking at the available operators I'd guess that the language is more "functionally", i.e. does not make use of side effects. Apart from that there seem to be records, with their parts accessible via a "dot" syntax (`RECORD.PART`).

Comment: So, thanks Daniel, I'm sure your term 'functionally' is much more accurate than my 'language'.  I get the record.part syntax, it's more the required elements and order of the operators that I'm getting stuck on.  I just gotta figure out the (Param1; Param2) part for each operator .  .I've been lurking for about a week trying to find other language with a common structure and thought I would break down and just ask if someone recognized it - hope that answers your question haccks.

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't assert this because I don't have experience with the language, this looks like ABAP to me, the high-level language created by the German software company SAP for its business applications.

Comment: I'll look into ABAP . . .might be something there. - Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

Many of the operators you've mentioned look like MySQL function names or keywords. Notable examples include:

- [`COUNT_DISTINCT`, which looks a lot like `COUNT(DISTINCT)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct)
- [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)
- [`INET_NTOA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa)
- [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)
- [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

However, many of the functions you've identified do *not* appear in MySQL; in particular, basic operators like `PLUS`, `MULTIPLY` and `EQUALS` are not functions in MySQL, and `LOGGED_USER_ID` and `WORKING_DAYS` do not appear in MySQL either. Additionally, the function call syntax you've described doesn't match what MySQL uses.

If I had to guess, I'd say you're looking at something custom that "compiles" expressions into MySQL queries.

Comment: That's the conclusion I'm coming too as well . .  .working now with a Nested IF statement, and, not knowing the exact syntax it keeps failing when I nest  3 . . . no case statement - - - leaves a little to be desired.  really appreciate you're suggestion